# How can I open link in adobe xd?

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd

I have an xd adobe link with full of the design pages. I want to open these design pages in adobe xd windows desktop application but I can't. How can I open this link in adobe xd windows desktop application?

Answer (score 2):

You need permission to open link from browser to adobexd.

Comment: How do you mean permission? Where is this achieved? Thanks

Comment: who owns the file link need to give permission